# If statement Confusion for method

Tags: java

I'm having an issue with understanding this code

```
public void changeHealthCoefficient(double delta)
```

which adds the value passed in the delta parameter to the `healthCoefficient` instance variable.

The parameter `delta` may be positive or negative, but if the new value of `healthCoefficient` would be less than or equal to `MINIMUM_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT` , in addition to changing the value of `healthCoefficient`, set the `isAlive` instance variable to `false`.

If the new value of `healthCoefficient` would be greater than `MAXIMUM_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT`, set `healthCoefficient` to `MAXIMUM_ HEALTH_COEFFICIENT`.

I did

```
if (newHealthCoefficient  <= MINIMUN_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT)
    newHealthCoefficient = MINIMUN_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT
```

Instead of

```
newHealthCoefficient >= MAXIMUM_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT 

newHealthCoefficient = MAXIMUM_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT
```

Comment: Given the lack of formatting, I'm surprised you can read it, much less understand it.

Comment: I tried my best to make it more readable, now you just need to actually ask a question.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this forum and Java but what would my if statement be? Cuz the one I am doing is wrong

Comment: Can someone please help

Comment: @user6394146: The wording here is confusing.  What exactly is the problem?  What isn't working?

Comment: If you want help, you need to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've described, it seems like you want something like:

```
public void changeHealthCoefficient(double delta)
{
    // adds the value passed in the delta parameter to the 
    // healthCoefficient instance variable
    healthCoefficient += delta;

    // if the new value of healthCoefficient would be less than or equal 
    // to MINIMUM_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT , in addition to changing the value of 
    // healthCoefficient, set the isAlive instance variable to false.
    if (healthCoefficient  <= MINIMUN_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT)
    {
        isAlive = false;
    }

    // if the new value of healthCoefficient would be greater than 
    // MAXIMUM_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT, set healthCoefficient to 
    // MAXIMUM_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT.
    if (healthCoefficient > MAXIMUM_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT)
    {
        healthCoefficient = MAXIMUM_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use newHealthCoefficient it says variable not found but in my default constructor I have public Guppy (double newHealthCoefficient)

Comment: I accidentally had it as newHealthCoefficient in the 1st if statement. I updated my answer to have it as healthCoefficient.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to enforce minimum or maximum values is to use the `Math.min` and `Math.max` methods.

For example:

```
healthCoefficient = Math.Min(healthCoefficient, MAXIMUM_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT);
```

sets the value to the smaller of the current value and the constant.

I would suggest, based on your question, that your health coefficient value should be in its own class. Very long variable names can be an indication that you are trying to distinguish variables from unrelated ones in an unrelated class.

So its possible that your code would be clearer with something like:

```
class HealthCoefficient {
    private static final double MAX = 100.0;
    private static final double MIN = 30.0;
    private double value;

    public void change(double delta) {
        value += delta;
        value = Math.min(value, MAX);
        value = Math.max(value, MIN);
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return value > MIN;
    }
}
```